# Run a script on variables from a list file

Tags: list, shell, for-loop

I have a script which includes the following step as the first step in a series of filters of genomics data:

```
 --option ~/folder$1/file$1 --option2 ~/folder$1/file$1 --indv NA12775 --options...
```

The script already uses a for-loop to go through folder/file indices 1-22. The option `--indv` takes a string, which is an identifiers. I have a separate list file which is just a column of "indv" identifiers:

```
NA06984
NA06986
NA06989
NA06994
NA07000
```

I have many such lists and I am looking for a solution to automatically take a single identifier from my list file, run the filtering script for "indv X" and then take the next consecutive identifier and repeat. Something like "for line in ID-list, run filter-script"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple `bash` methods for doing this:

```
for indv in $(<list-of-indv-values.txt)
do
  something something .... ${indv} .....
done
```

or

```
while read indv
do
  something something ... ${indv} .....
done < list-of-indv-values.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xargs` for this:

```
xargs -I {} ./myprogram --indv {} < indvlist.txt
```

Comment: What should I use inside of the script as a placeholder for --indv {}?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean inside of my script I am currently putting something like `--indv NA07000` so how would I modify this line in the script to take an argument from the list?

Comment: @isosceleswheel: `{}` takes the place of `NA07000` in your example; use of `xargs` is both simpler and faster than the `bash`-only solution you accepted; it is simpler in that you don't need a loop to enumerate the `indv` values anymore: assuming that the name of the command you want to invoke is `./myprogram`, you'd use `xargs -I {} ./myprogram ~/folder$1/file$1 --option2 ~/folder$1/file$1 --indv {} --options... < list-of-indv-values.txt`

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, I already spent the morning building up a nested for-loop solution which works well, but I will also try the xargs version, since you say it would be more efficient. For this particular project there are not too many variables to loop through (<100), but I am always looking for more techniques to add to my toolbox